# how can I pass an argument to a function handle, but interpret it only on call time?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

What I want to do is:

```
a = 5 
foo = @(x) x+a
a = 3
foo(1) % recieve 4
```

Instead, I only get 6! On several other tests I ran, I get that `a` is evaluated when `foo` is, and and not when `foo` is called.

For various reasons, I can't work with

```
foo = @(x,a) x+a
```

Comment: Sorry, some clarification: you are telling that you expect the value to be 4 but you get 6 ? or you are expecting it to be 6 and you get 4.

Comment: I'm getting 6 but expecting 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking to do is not recommended. It will be difficult to debug.

That said, it can be done using the `evalin` function to reach out and get the current value of `a`.

```
a=5; 
foo = @(x)evalin('caller','a')+x; 
foo(1)  %Returns 6

a=3; 
foo(1)  %Returns 5
```

Better (much better!) would be to push the definition of `a` into an apprpriate data structure or object, and create a function `getCurrentValueOfA()`. Then you can define `foo` as

```
foo = @(x) getCurrentValueOfA() + x;
```

Comment: getCurrentValueOfA is clearly a better debuggable option, only that it have the disatvantage of readability. Anyway, both solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: the '('caller')' parameter is to indicate we're evaluating on call time?

Comment: No. The 'caller' parameter mean evaluate the expression in the calling function's namespace. The other option is 'base' which tells it to use the top level namespace.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an anonymous function in Matlab it stores the current value of any variables that it needs and that are not part of its inputs.

So, when you created `foo` like this:

```
a = 5
foo = @(x) x+a
```

It stored the equivalent of this:

```
foo = @(x) x+5
```

Even if you change later the value of `a` the value of that constant stored inside `foo`won't change.

If in the other hand you want the value of `a` to change, you have to accept `a` as a parameter of the function as well.

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of stored data with the `functions` command:

```
>> a = 5 
foo = @(x) x+a
a =
     5
foo = 
    @(x)x+a
>> handleInfo = functions(foo)
handleInfo = 
     function: '@(x)x+a'
         type: 'anonymous'
         file: ''
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
>> handleInfo.workspace{1}
ans = 
    a: 5
```